# Adding two hex numbers javascript with bit shift

Tags: javascript, hex, bit-shift

I am trying to add two numbers in JavaScript, represented in hexadecimal base, in the following way:

```
var a = 0x0028 << 16 + 0x0010;
```

and what I expect to get is 0x00280010. Unfortunately JavaScript makes a equals 40, (which of course is 0x0028). If I shift the bits without adding 0x0010, everything works fine, I get 2621440 for a, which is 0x280000. Why adding 0x0010 yields such results for a.
I am not that good at this kind of arithmetic, am I doing or expecting something wrong?
Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use brackets: `+` has higher precedence over `<<`.

```
var a = (0x0028 << 16) + 0x0010 // note the brackets.
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks a lot

Comment: You're Most Welcome. Its time for you to take a coffee break I guess;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put brackets around the shift as it has lower precedence than the plus ([see this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

```
a = (0x0028 << 16) + 0x0010
> 2621456
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't check this